# Using .Net's CheckSignature on a System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml fails on test servers, but not development machine

Tags: .net, xml, xml-signature

I'm trying to verify that a certain xml document has not been tampered with by checking its signature.

On my development machine this works just fine, but on our test servers it always fails. The development machine is Windows 10, the test servers are Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012.

I've managed to create a SignedXML debug log, and this is what it looks like:

Development:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 1 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, BeginCheckSignatureFormat] Checking signature format using format validator "[System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.DefaultSignatureFormatValidator".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 6 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, FormatValidationResult] Signature format validation was successful.
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 1 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, BeginCheckSignatureFormat] Checking signature format using format validator "[System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.DefaultSignatureFormatValidator".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 6 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, FormatValidationResult] Signature format validation was successful.
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 2 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, BeginCheckSignedInfo] Checking signature on SignedInfo with id "(null)".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 7 : [SignedXml#03d410d5, NamespacePropagation] Propagating namespace xmlns="<namespace here>".
```

And so on.

On the test servers it pretty much starts out the same:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 1 : [SignedXml#00e65efe, BeginCheckSignatureFormat] Checking signature format using format validator "[System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.DefaultSignatureFormatValidator".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 6 : [SignedXml#00e65efe, FormatValidationResult] Signature format validation was successful.
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 1 : [SignedXml#00e65efe, BeginCheckSignatureFormat] Checking signature format using format validator "[System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.DefaultSignatureFormatValidator".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 6 : [SignedXml#00e65efe, FormatValidationResult] Signature format validation was successful.
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 2 : [SignedXml#00e65efe, BeginCheckSignedInfo] Checking signature on SignedInfo with id "(null)".
```

But it just ends there. No Information: 7 is ever logged, and the function returns false.

The Test Servers have at least .Net 4.5.2 installed, so I am presuming they cannot be having trouble with SHA-256 signing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How does it fail? Returns false or throws an exception? What does the code look like in the call to `CheckSignature`? Specifically, do you check the certificate's validity or not? If SHA-256 is not available you will get an exception.

Comment: @AndersAbel It just returns false. I've managed to figure it out over the weekend, Will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the weekend I figured it out.

Apparently the XML I was getting (Federation data from Azure AD) is signed using a cryptographical method that is not working in .Net 4.5.2, but does work in 4.6.2.

After updating one of the test servers to .Net 4.6.2 this morning, CheckSignature indeed returned true.